# NCover Exclude Attribute in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, ncover

I am have successfully setup Sonar to do some analysis on my C# project where we are already making use of NCover. Our code has NCover exclude attributes and we would like to use these in Sonar to make the analysis meaningful. I have managed to find a few things on the web (e.g. http://marc.info/?l=sonar-user&m=133896735312253) but the links to the JIRA is dead and doensnt ever seem to have been addressed. Does anyone know if it is possible to make use of NCover exclude attributes within Sonar? If not then we will have to look at alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube C# plugin (since version 3.x) only imports code coverage reports generated by 3rd party tools. The information on which lines are to be covered by tests (i.e. "executable" lines), as well as which lines actually were covered by tests, are provided by the report generated by the tool.

These NCover exclusions should be applied by NCover itself, and should not require special support from SonarQube.